# Exporting standalone web services using JAX-WS throws Error

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, spring-remoting, spring-bean

I am facing issues while exposing standalone web services using spring jax-ws SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter for remoting. Below is my configuration and error message while starting the application. I am using JBoss 5.1.0 as application server. Please help me with the configuration. I am not using any com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet as I want to expose the web service as standalone.

My applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<context:annotation-config />

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
```

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter">
    <property name="baseAddress" value="http://localhost:8989/services" />
</bean>

<bean id="carServiceEndpoint" class="com.webservices.CarServiceEndpoint" />
```

My endpoint class:

```
@Service("CarService")
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.webservices.ICarServiceEndpoint", serviceName = "CarService")
public class CarServiceEndpoint implements ICarServiceEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    CarService carService;

    @Override
    public Car getCar() {
        return carService.getCar();
    }

    @Override
    public Car process(Car car) {
        return carService.getCar();
    }
}
```

My interface that endpoint implements:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(serviceName = "CarService")
public interface ICarServiceEndpoint {

    @WebMethod
    public Car getCar();

    @WebMethod
    public Car process(@WebParam(name = "car") Car car);

}
```

My domain object:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Car")
public class Car implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String carId;

    private String carName;

    public String getCarId() {
        return carId;
    }

    public void setCarId(String carId) {
        this.carId = carId;
    }

    public String getCarName() {
        return carName;
    }

    public void setCarName(String carName) {
        this.carName = carName;
    }

}
```

Error message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter#0'
>   defined in
>   ZipEntryHandler@1724575[path=provider.war/WEB-INF/lib/core-services-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/module-beans/applicationContext.xml
>   context=file:/D:/Softwares/JBoss5.1.x/jboss510/server/NEWFW_SERVER/deploy/
>   real=file:/D:/Softwares/JBoss5.1.x/jboss510/server/NEWFW_SERVER/deploy/provider.war/WEB-INF/lib/core-services-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/module-beans/applicationContext.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class
>   com.webservices.CarServiceEndpoint$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$3002d7c has
>   neither @WebService nor @WebServiceProvider annotation

Comment: The configuration works fine if I don't have WebMethod which takes input parameters. If I remove the below method it works fine:
@WebMethod
    public Car process(@WebParam(name = "car") Car car);